# Detect Eyes Using Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-recognition, eye-tracking

I have tryed hough   circle  algo but it give not acceptable out put of detecting 
eyes . Can we find way to get the eyes detect in image I having face front ...

Comment: did you try http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13716 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [implementation](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/research/nface/index.html) from Oxford's Visual Geometry Group. Their pipeline consists of a Viola-Jones face detector at the front and then 9 face landmarks including inner and outer corners of both eyes, center/edge of nostrils, and mouth corners.

I've used this with some success in the past. If you want an exact eye corner, then some additional refinement may be necessary as this includes a model that tries to make a best fit for the entire face.